# Create dynamic link on Firebase using core php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

In my firebase account, I create dynamic link manually and I got that dynamic link in my application, but the issue is that I need to create dynamic link randomly using core php.

I have tried below steps

1 Step : Goes to Firebase console account

2 Step : Select app and then under Grow > dynamic links > new dynamic link

Here I am able to create manually, but not able to create using core php.

Answer (score 12):

Easy way to do that

```
function shorten_URL ($longUrl) {
  $key = 'WEB_API_KEY';
  $url = 'https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=' . $key;
  $data = array(
     "dynamicLinkInfo" => array(
        "dynamicLinkDomain" => "YOUR_DOMAIN.page.link",
        "link" => $longUrl
     )
  );

  $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');

  $ch = curl_init ();
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );

  $data = curl_exec ( $ch );
  curl_close ( $ch );

  $short_url = json_decode($data);
  if(isset($short_url->error)){
      return $short_url->error->message;
  } else {
      return $short_url->shortLink;
  }

}

// Call the function with the URL
shorten_URL('https://YOUR_LONG_URL');
```

All what you have to do is to add your firebase domain from dynamic links and your web api key from settings.

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply.. this information is very useful but i want to know , is this short link created by this code will reflect in firebase account?

Comment: Console only view the analytics of dynamic links created at console but to retrieve the analytics data for REST API dynamic links you'll have to use.  "Firebase Dynamic Links Analytics API" 
you'll find here example for http request https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics.

Comment: Hi @abdallah, I have generated the dynamic link using above code, if i want to see generated link then where i can view in firebase portal? I go to Dynamic Link UI but nothing is showing under my domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) composer package to create dynamic links via Firebase API. See [setup guide](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html) and [dynamic links API](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dynamic-links.html).

Also there's a simpler way. You may want to manually construct dynamic link instead of calling Firebase API. I used [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) and created [mxl/firebase-dynamic-link](https://github.com/mxl/firebase-dynamic-link-php) composer package.

1. Install it with composer:

   ```
   $ composer require mxl/firebase-dynamic-link
   ```
2. Build dynamic link:

   ```
   use MichaelLedin\FirebaseDynamicLink\DynamicLink;

   DynamicLink::for('your_subdomain.page.link', 'https://your_domain.com/path/to/page')->build();
   ```